# TexShop - enable autocompletion by default?

Tags: texshop

Every time I launch TexShop, I have to activate the Auto Completion feature again, although I had already done that the last TexShop session. It appears really inconvenient to me - why can't I just keep it "on" for default across every session. Is there a way to do it? I googled and read the documentation but couldn't find the answer. If it's the default/intended behavior of TexShop then it appears weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just directly in the preferences -> Code -> Editor -> Autocompletion(checkbox) This information is not obvious on its documentation though.